Nvidea update will not update driver 24.04 LTS seems a bug at the moment
Last update has left my system unstable,  when booting I get an unresponsive black screen, hard reboot gets me to Grub and have to use my old USB keyboard.It then load using the Nouveau driver and not the GTX 650.
Using Apt-get I get an error:
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
udevadm hwdb is deprecated. Use systemd-hwdb instead.
udevadm hwdb is deprecated. Use systemd-hwdb instead.
udevadm hwdb is deprecated. Use systemd-hwdb instead.
udevadm hwdb is deprecated. Use systemd-hwdb instead.
udevadm hwdb is deprecated. Use systemd-hwdb instead.
udevadm hwdb is deprecated. Use systemd-hwdb instead.
udevadm hwdb is deprecated. Use systemd-hwdb instead.
udevadm hwdb is deprecated. Use systemd-hwdb instead.
udevadm hwdb is deprecated. Use systemd-hwdb instead.
udevadm hwdb is deprecated. Use systemd-hwdb instead.
udevadm hwdb is deprecated. Use systemd-hwdb instead.
udevadm hwdb is deprecated. Use systemd-hwdb instead.
udevadm hwdb is deprecated. Use systemd-hwdb instead.
udevadm hwdb is deprecated. Use systemd-hwdb instead.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  nvidia-kernel-source-560
Recommended packages:
  libnvidia-compute-560:i386 libnvidia-decode-560:i386 libnvidia-encode-560:i386 libnvidia-fbc1-560:i386
  libnvidia-gl-560:i386
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  nvidia-dkms-560-open nvidia-driver-560-open nvidia-kernel-source-560-open
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  nvidia-dkms-560 nvidia-driver-560 nvidia-kernel-source-560
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 3 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
14 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 52.1 MB of archives.
After this operation, 61.5 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu noble/main amd64 nvidia-kernel-source-560 amd64 560.35.03-0ubuntu0~gpu24.04.4 [51.5 MB]
Get:2 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu noble/main amd64 nvidia-dkms-560 amd64 560.35.03-0ubuntu0~gpu24.04.4 [35.9 kB]
Get:3 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu noble/main amd64 nvidia-driver-560 amd64 560.35.03-0ubuntu0~gpu24.04.4 [493 kB]
Fetched 52.1 MB in 10s (5,172 kB/s)                                                                          
(Reading database ... 497688 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing nvidia-driver-560-open (560.35.03-0ubuntu0~gpu24.04.4) ...
Removing nvidia-dkms-560-open (560.35.03-0ubuntu0~gpu24.04.4) ...
Removing all DKMS Modules
Done.
INFO:Disable nvidia
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/dell_latitude
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/lenovo_thinkpad
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/put_your_quirks_here
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Removing nvidia-kernel-source-560-open (560.35.03-0ubuntu0~gpu24.04.4) ...
Selecting previously unselected package nvidia-kernel-source-560.
(Reading database ... 497200 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../nvidia-kernel-source-560_560.35.03-0ubuntu0~gpu24.04.4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nvidia-kernel-source-560 (560.35.03-0ubuntu0~gpu24.04.4) ...
Preparing to unpack .../nvidia-dkms-560_560.35.03-0ubuntu0~gpu24.04.4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nvidia-dkms-560 (560.35.03-0ubuntu0~gpu24.04.4) ...
Selecting previously unselected package nvidia-driver-560.
Preparing to unpack .../nvidia-driver-560_560.35.03-0ubuntu0~gpu24.04.4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nvidia-driver-560 (560.35.03-0ubuntu0~gpu24.04.4) ...
Setting up nvidia-compute-utils-560 (560.35.03-0ubuntu0~gpu24.04.4) ...
fatal: Only one or two names allowed.
dpkg: error processing package nvidia-compute-utils-560 (--configure):
 installed nvidia-compute-utils-560 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 51
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nvidia-driver-560:
 nvidia-driver-560 depends on nvidia-compute-utils-560 (= 560.35.03-0ubuntu0~gpu24.04.4); however:
  Package nvidia-compute-utils-560 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package nvidia-driver-560 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up sssd-common (2.9.4-1.1ubuntu6.1) ...
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Creating SSSD system user & group...
fatal: Only one or two names allowed.
dpkg: error processing package sssd-common (--configure):
 installed sssd-common package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 51
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of sssd-proxy:
 sssd-proxy depends on sssd-common (= 2.9.4-1.1ubuntu6.1); however:
  Package sssd-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package sssd-proxy (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up nvidia-kernel-source-560 (560.35.03-0ubuntu0~gpu24.04.4) ...
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of sssd-ipa:
 sssd-ipa depends on sssd-common (= 2.9.4-1.1ubuntu6.1); however:
  Package sssd-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package sssd-ipa (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of sssd-ad-common:
 sssd-ad-common depends on sssd-common (= 2.9.4-1.1ubuntu6.1); however:
  Package sssd-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package sssd-ad-common (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
              No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                            dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of sssd-krb5-common:
 sssd-krb5-common depends on sssd-common (= 2.9.4-1.1ubuntu6.1); however:
  Package sssd-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package sssd-krb5-common (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up flatpak (1.14.6-1ubuntu0.1) ...
fatal: Only one or two names allowed.
dpkg: error processing package flatpak (--configure):
 installed flatpak package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 51
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of sssd-krb5:
 sssd-krb5 depends on sssd-common (= 2.9.4-1.1ubuntu6.1); however:
  Package sssd-common is not configured yet.
 sssd-krb5 depends on sssd-krb5-common (= 2.9.4-1.1ubuntu6.1); however:
  Package sssd-krb5-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package sssd-krb5 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of sssd:
 sssd depends on sssd-common (= 2.9.4-1.1ubuntu6.1); however:
  Package sssd-common is not configured yet.
 sssd depends on sssd-ipa (= 2.9.4-1.1ubuntu6.1); however:
  Package sssd-ipa is not configured yet.
 sssd depends on sssd-krb5 (= 2.9.4-1.1ubuntu6.1); however:
  Package sssd-krb5 is not configured yet.
 sssd depends on sssd-proxy (= 2.9.4-1.1ubuntu6.1); however:
  Package sssd-proxy is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package sssd (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of sssd-ldap:
 sssd-ldap depends on sssd-common (= 2.9.4-1.1ubuntu6.1); however:
  Package sssd-common is not configured yet.
 sssd-ldap depends on sssd-krb5-common (= 2.9.4-1.1ubuntu6.1); however:
  Package sssd-krb5-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package sssd-ldap (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up network-manager-openvpn (1.10.2-4build2) ...
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              fatal: Specify only one name in this mode.
dpkg: error processing package network-manager-openvpn (--configure):
 installed network-manager-openvpn package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 51
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of sssd-ad:
 sssd-ad depends on sssd-ad-common (= 2.9.4-1.1ubuntu6.1); however:
  Package sssd-ad-common is not configured yet.
 sssd-ad depends on sssd-common (= 2.9.4-1.1ubuntu6.1); however:
  Package sssd-common is not configured yet.
 sssd-ad depends on sssd-krb5-common (= 2.9.4-1.1ubuntu6.1); however:
  Package sssd-krb5-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package sssd-ad (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up nvidia-dkms-560 (560.35.03-0ubuntu0~gpu24.04.4) ...
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
INFO:Enable nvidia
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/dell_latitude
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/lenovo_thinkpad
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/put_your_quirks_here
Loading new nvidia-560.35.03 DKMS files...
Building for 6.8.0-45-lowlatency
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 6.8.0-45-lowlatency
Done.

nvidia.ko.zst:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/6.8.0-45-lowlatency/updates/dkms/

nvidia-modeset.ko.zst:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/6.8.0-45-lowlatency/updates/dkms/

nvidia-drm.ko.zst:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/6.8.0-45-lowlatency/updates/dkms/

nvidia-uvm.ko.zst:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/6.8.0-45-lowlatency/updates/dkms/

nvidia-peermem.ko.zst:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/6.8.0-45-lowlatency/updates/dkms/
depmod....
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of network-manager-openvpn-gnome:
 network-manager-openvpn-gnome depends on network-manager-openvpn (= 1.10.2-4build2); however:
  Package network-manager-openvpn is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package network-manager-openvpn-gnome (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.142ubuntu25.2) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-6.8.0-45-lowlatency
Errors were encountered while processing:
 nvidia-compute-utils-560
 nvidia-driver-560
 sssd-common
 sssd-proxy
 sssd-ipa
 sssd-ad-common
 sssd-krb5-common
 flatpak
 sssd-krb5
 sssd
 sssd-ldap
 network-manager-openvpn
 sssd-ad
 network-manager-openvpn-gnome
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Sorry for the long post.
Cheers Bob
